# Simple Java web service connecting to mySql not working

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

I decided to try to connect a java client to a mysql db running on wamp.
Can anybody tell me why im getting this runtime problem?

My DBConnect() class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DbConnect {

    private Connection conn;
    private Statement statement;
    private ResultSet resultset;

    public DbConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/pk","root","");
        }       catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public String getData(){
        String result ="";
        try {
            resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from data_user");
            while(resultset.next())
            {
                result+=resultset.getString("userFirstName");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return result;  
    }
```

My main() class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DbConnect conn = new DbConnect();
        System.out.println(conn.getData());
    }
```

My error at runtime

> Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> > The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> >     ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> >     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> >     DbConnect.getData(DbConnect.java:26)    at Main.main(Main.java:8) ERROR:
> >     JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
> >     JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]
> >
> > ```
> > }
> > ```

Offending line

```
    resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from data_user");
```

Comment: It's just a regular null pointer.

Comment: Thx Im not sure why this is a null pointer. can you explain what im missing?

Comment: There are many questions here already about NPEs.

Comment: In this case i open my connection, i instantiate my statement and execute it in connection with a resultSet

Comment: Open your debugger and watch the variables to see what is null then.

Comment: Please don't completely change your question after you've received answers.

Comment: how can you not change your approach if people are indicating the error is in a diff place? I was thrown by the weird red JDWP error.  that would be insanity. The question hasnt changed. I asked where the null is likely to be, its hardly completely changing it. try not to be as aggressive in future and i'll try not to miss obvious errors.

Comment: @takendarkk  -my bad, it the connection is null as it fails to connect - timed out error...i'll have to try to chase that now thx,

Comment: Just a quick thought but is your database server running?

Comment: It is yes but thats not to say it wasnt, to be honest with the combination of server performance issues, eclipse issues and wamp config it was a mix of things hut essentially it camedown to a null connection due to a closed port

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didnt instantiate your statement, unless you are missing some code.  You need to do something like the following: statement=conn.createStatement();
Take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) example

Comment: Thx but i put this in and still get the error. Im not sure why this is a null pointer. can you explain what im missing?

Comment: Ok so the connection init didnt work. arggh. Fromt he tutorial im using i dont need to init the statment but what do i know....thx for your help.